# Stability of indefinitely damped mechanical system with diagonal stiffness

Tags: linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

I'm trying to find conditions for the asymptotic stability of the following linear system,
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{I \ddot{x}} + \mathbf{B \dot{x}} + \mathbf{K x} = 0
\end{equation}
given the following conditions, $\mathbf{K} \in \mathbf{\mathcal{R}}^{n\times n}$ is diagonal and positive definite with simple eigenvalues and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbf{\mathcal{R}}^{n\times n}$ is asymmetric, indefinite and positive stable. Specifically, I'm looking for necessary and sufficient conditions that guarantee stability.

I know that there are sufficient conditions for systems where $\mathbf{B}$ is positive stable and $\mathbf{K}$ is positive definite (which are applicable to our system). Note that additionally, we have that $\mathbf{K}$ is diagonal. Does this lead to simpler sufficient conditions than those found by [Kliem & Pommer](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00033-007-7072-0.pdf)?

Also, the stability problem can be interpreted as the gyroscopic stabilization of an indefinitely damped system,
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{I \ddot{x}} + (\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{G}) \mathbf{\dot{x}} + \mathbf{K x} = 0
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{D} + \mathbf{G}$, such that $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{D}^\top$ is indefinite, and $\mathbf{G} = -\mathbf{G}^\top$. The necessary conditions for a matrix $\mathbf{G}$ to exist such that it achieves gyroscopic stabilization are $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{D})>0$ and $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{K}^{-1}\mathbf{D})>0$, which have also been conjectured to be sufficient, [Damm & Homeyer](https://folk.ntnu.no/skoge/prost/proceedings/ifac11-proceedings/data/html/papers/1773.pdf). To the best of my knowledge, the conjecture has been shown to be true for 2, 3, and 4D systems, but not for a $n$-dimensional system. Does having $\mathbf{K}$ to be diagonal help to show that these conditions are sufficient for a n-dimensional system?